# Dejar solo 2 decimales despues del punto en MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT Clientes.Nombre, 
       Clientes.Apellido, 
       Lotes.NoLote, Lotes.Precio, 
       Sum(Pagos.Monto) AS SumaDeMonto 
FROM (Clientes INNER JOIN Lotes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Lotes.IdCliente) 
INNER JOIN Pagos 
ON (Lotes.NoLote = Pagos.NoLote) 
AND (Clientes.IdCliente = Pagos.IdCliente) 
GROUP BY Clientes.Nombre, Clientes.Apellido, Lotes.NoLote, Lotes.Precio;
```

Lo que deseo es que la columna `SumaDeMontos` tenga unicamente 2 decimales ya que a la hora de la consulta me aparecen 4 decimales.

Agradecere de su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que gestor usas?

Comment: lo estoy trabajando en access y los datos los muestro en java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encierra y usa la función DECIMAL para usar solo decimales. Tu suma en un tipo de dato como decimal. Observa:

```
SELECT Clientes.Nombre, 
       Clientes.Apellido, 
       Lotes.NoLote, Lotes.Precio, 
       CAST(Sum(Pagos.Monto) AS DECIMAL(10,2))AS SumaDeMonto 
FROM (Clientes INNER JOIN Lotes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Lotes.IdCliente) 
INNER JOIN Pagos 
ON (Lotes.NoLote = Pagos.NoLote) 
AND (Clientes.IdCliente = Pagos.IdCliente) 
GROUP BY Clientes.Nombre, Clientes.Apellido, Lotes
```

Actualización

Si te da error de acuerdo a tu consulta por la suma de los registros, te recomiendo también hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT
temp_table.*,
CAST(temp_table.SumaDeMonto AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS suma_con_cast
FROM (
    SELECT Clientes.Nombre, 
           Clientes.Apellido, 
           Lotes.NoLote, Lotes.Precio, 
           Sum(Pagos.Monto) AS SumaDeMonto 
    FROM (Clientes INNER JOIN Lotes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Lotes.IdCliente) 
    INNER JOIN Pagos 
    ON (Lotes.NoLote = Pagos.NoLote) 
    AND (Clientes.IdCliente = Pagos.IdCliente) 
    GROUP BY Clientes.Nombre, Clientes.Apellido, Lotes.NoLote, Lotes.Precio;
) AS temp_table
```

Comment: error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresion de consulta CAST(Sum(Pagos.Monto) AS DECIMAL(10,2))

Me desplego ese error. :(

Comment: me podrian ayudar por favor.

Comment: claro, te edito la respuesta